# How to change "Call Script" Label in the Workflow Left Panel in the Unified Service Desk Agent Scripting

Tags: crm, unified-service-desk

I'm trying to change the Call Script Label on the Left Panel Pane of the Unified Service Desk.

Doing the SetTheme action but only changing text property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to configure or change Call Script name from within USD. 
What you can try is that create your own agent scripts and call them from your code inside Unified Service Desk. Make them more generic so you would be able to change the name and what not through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you'd have to be using a custom Panel Layout Hosted Control.  If you do that, you can edit the XAML and the title of the Call Script section is in there and you can change it.

[MS USD Custom Panel Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-service-desk/use-custom-panel-types-panel-layouts-unified-service-desk?view=dynamics-usd-4.2)